# How to listen a django web api from celery task?

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I created a project using Django, Celery, and celery beat for scheduling tasks. I created a task using celery.

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def my_task(self):

    # How can I listen if a post API is requested from here?

    return "Task Successful"
```

I want this task to listen to a web API if it is requested. Is it possible?

Comment: You can simply call the task from the needed endpoint

Comment: The task is assumed to run on a given schedule. I can't call it from the API.

Comment: Ok, then in the endpoint create entities of tasks that are to be processed, and store them in db or redis, and simply process them at your specific schedule